# SQL find rows in groups where a column has a null and a non-null value

Tags: sql, sql-server

## The Data

```
   row    ID YEAR  PROD STA                    DATE
    01    01 2011 APPLE NEW 2011-11-18 00:00:00.000
    02    01 2011 APPLE NEW 2011-11-18 00:00:00.000
    03    01 2013 APPLE OLD NULL
    04    01 2013 APPLE OLD NULL
    05    02 2013 APPLE OLD 2014-04-08 00:00:00.000
    06    02 2013 APPLE OLD 2014-04-08 00:00:00.000
    07    02 2013 APPLE OLD 2014-11-17 10:50:14.113
    08    02 2013 APPLE OLD 2014-11-17 10:46:04.947
    09    02 2013 MELON OLD 2014-11-17 11:01:19.657
    10    02 2013 MELON OLD 2014-11-17 11:19:35.547
    11    02 2013 MELON OLD NULL
    12    02 2013 MELON OLD 2014-11-21 10:32:36.017
    13    03 2006 APPLE NEW 2007-04-11 00:00:00.000
    14    03 2006 APPLE NEW 2007-04-11 00:00:00.000
    15    04 2004 APPLE OTH 2004-09-27 00:00:00.000
    16    04 2004 APPLE OTH NULL
```

ROW is not a column in the table. Is just to show which records i want.

## The question

I need to find rows where a group consisting of (ID, YEAR, PROD, STA) has at least one NULL DATE and a non-NULL DATE.

## Expected result

From the above dataset this would be rows 9 to 12 and 15 to 16

Im sitting in front od SSMS and have no idea how to get this. Thinking about `group by` and `exists` but really no idea.

Comment: Why does your ID column have multiple rows with the same ID.  Shouldn't ID be unique?

Comment: That is not a primary key but the result of an already aggregated query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `COUNT ... OVER`:

```
SELECT ID, YEAR, PROD, STA, [DATE]
FROM (
  SELECT ID, YEAR, PROD, STA, [DATE],
         COUNT(IIF([DATE] IS NULL, 1, NULL)) OVER 
              (PARTITION BY ID, YEAR, PROD, STA) AS cnt_nulls,
         COUNT(IIF([DATE] IS NOT NULL, 1, NULL)) OVER
               (PARTITION BY ID, YEAR, PROD, STA) AS cnt_not_nulls
  FROM mytable) AS t
WHERE t.cnt_nulls > 0 AND t.cnt_not_nulls > 0
```

The window version of `COUNT` is applied *twice* over `ID, YEAR, PROD, STA` partitions of data: it returns *for every row* the population of the current partition. The count is *conditionally* performed:

- the first `COUNT` counts the number of `NULL` `[Date]` values within the partition
- the second `COUNT` counts the number of `NOT NULL` `[Date]` values within the partition.

The outer query checks for partitions having a count of *at least one* for both of the two `COUNT` functions of the inner query.

Comment: I dont understand this but i accept it - it works! :)

Comment: @RobertNiestroj Would have been nice if they put some effort into explaining the query rather then just posting a chunk of T-SQL.

Comment: @Lankymart Ok, you are right. Please check the edit I made.

Comment: After reading about OVER and PARTITION BY i understand the query :)